# "text-overflow: ellipsis" not working well in firefox with floating element around

Tags: html, css, firefox

see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9v8faLeh/1/

I have two elements `.text` and `.badge` in a `.container` with a limit width:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="badge">(*)</span>
    <span class="text">this is a long long long long text.</span>
</div>
```

the `.badge` element may not exist in a `.container` according to the data. if a `.badge` exist, I want the `.badge` element to float to right. and if the `.text` is too long, the text should ellipsis.

```
.container {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.badge {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

if you open the jsfiddle link in Chrome or IE, it displays correctly as my expectation.
but if open in Firefox, the `.text` and `.badge` are overlay if the text is so long.

I don't want to use any JavaScript. how can I achieve the same result in FireFox?

Answer (score -1):

Just put `<span class="badge">(*)</span>` inside `<span class="text">this is a long long long long text.</span>` like this:

```
<span class="text">this is a long long long long text.<span class="badge">(*)</span></span>
```

and then in CSS

```
.container {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
}
.badge {
    display:inline-block;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but it doesn't work. see http://jsfiddle.net/9v8faLeh/2/  the badge disappears...do I change correctly?

Comment: wait, I understand you want it to disappear. IN your original version it didn't disappear at all in FF

Comment: I want that if the badge has no class '.hide', it should always show in the right of the div.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear that, the width of the `.badge` may change. the demo shows `(*)`, it may also be `(****)`, so a fixed padding won't work in this case.

Comment: then if you don't have at least 1 fixed size, I can't imagine how to work this out with ellipsis. Maybe try using calc for the padding, but really don't know if it will work

Comment: but if you check the jsfiddle in Chrome or IE, it works and no fixed padding defined.

Comment: I mean the specific Firefox case