# Why does Chrome cutting text with ellipsis while Firefox doesn't?

Tags: css, firefox, markup

So I have a simple markup with fixed-width container, one floating right badge and text inside container. I would like text to be cutted with ellipsis when it reaches badge, but it won't work for Firefox.

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="to-right">toRight</span>
   <span class="left">Cutting text very very long</span>
</div>
```

Css file:

```
.container {
   border: solid 1px silver;
   width: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.to-right {
   float: right;
   background-color: green;
}
```

Why and what should I do to make it work consistent?
http://codepen.io/huston007/pen/gPLOaq

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396519/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working-well-in-firefox-with-floating-element-arou

Comment: It seems to be a known bug of Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=944200

Comment: I'm not sure how it is defined in the specs, but the reason why you don't see the dots in Firefox is, because that `to-right` that floats right seems to extend the boundary of the element so the dots are below the `to-right`  element.

Comment: So if size of floating element is known it is actually easy to solve by spacings http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgNoGw